# Why can't I select Google Chrome as default browser in application settings?

Tags: applications, settings, google-chrome

I have a bunch of browsers installed and they all show up as browsers in the system settings. All of them except for Chrome. I've tried reinstalling and uninstalling and re-installing and neither seems to work.

Could anyone offer advice on how I might fix this?

This is the screen I'm talking about:
[image]

Comment: where did you downloaded chrome from? Terminal? Software Center? website? or other?

Comment: the google chrome website.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how to get the browser in the list. And the suggestions below will not be a complete answer. But maybe this workaround helps you to find a solution:

In file

```
 ~/.config/mimeapps.list
```

and in "Default Applications" section you can change the default app for "browser relevant" mimetypes (e.g. "http", "https", "html", ...).

Maybe a "search and replace" (midori.desktop => chrome.desktop) is exactly what you want.

**Untested! Before you start backup the file!**